# How to make a multiple corpora in R

Tags: r, aggregate, text-mining, corpus

This is a car review data which has more than 40,000 rows and each review has more than 500 characters. This is sample data : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZRwzYH5McZIP2NLKxncmFaQ0mX1Pe0GShTMu57Tac_E

```
| brand  | review          | favorite        | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 | c8 |
| brand1 | 500 characters1 | 100 characters1 |    |    |    |    |    |  
| brand2 | 500 characters2 | 100 Characters2 |    |    |    |    |    | 
| brand2 | 500 characters3 | 100 Characters3 |    |    |    |    |    |
| brand2 | 500 characters4 | 100 Characters4 |    |    |    |    |    | 
| brand3 | 500 characters5 | 100 Characters5 |    |    |    |    |    | 
| brand3 | 500 characters6 | 100 characters6 |    |    |    |    |    |
```

I'd like to merge review column by brands like this :

```
| Brand  | review          | favorite        | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 | c8 |
| brand1 | 500 characters1 | 100 characters1 |    |    |    |    |    |  
| brand2 | 500 characters2 | 100 Characters2 |    |    |    |    |    | 
|        | 500 characters3 | 100 Characters3 |    |    |    |    |    |
|        | 500 characters4 | 100 Characters4 |    |    |    |    |    | 
| brand3 | 500 characters5 | 100 Characters5 |    |    |    |    |    | 
|        | 500 characters6 | 100 characters6 |    |    |    |    |    |
```

So, I tired to use aggregate().

```
temp <- aggregate(data$review ~ data$brand , data, as.list )
```

But, It takes very long.

Is there any simple way to merge that? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you add a small example of your desired result?  I can't picture it (what happens to the rest of the columns?).  Also, you might consider changing the title/tags to something more general.  Your question seems to be one about data manipulation rather than one that is specific to text mining or corpus.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting them on each factor and then pasting them together.  `aggregate()` is a horribly slow function and should be avoided for all but the smallest datasets.

This should do the trick:  (note I downloaded your Google file as `sampleDF.csv` here)

```
sampleDF <- read.csv("~/Downloads/sampleDF.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# aggregate text by brand
brand.split <- split(sampleDF$text, as.factor(sampleDF$Brand))
brand.grouped <- sapply(brand.split, paste, collapse = " ")

# aggregate favorite by brand
favorite.split <- split(sampleDF$favorite, as.factor(sampleDF$Brand))
favorite.grouped <- sapply(favorite.split, paste, collapse = " ")

newDf <- data.frame(brand = names(brand.split),
                    text <- favorite.grouped,
                    favorite <- favorite.grouped,
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

If you want to bring in other variables they will need to vary at the brand level only.